# SqliteDatabaseCpp(14550): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Caches, db=xxx

Tags: android, jquery, sqlite, cordova

am  working on phonegap app,i have error on  phone gap android 4.0.4 version.This error ocur while iam try to insert the query or update the query.But it works on ios or samsung 7 inch tablet.i dont know why this error is occur.The following code  is use to insert the query:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {                      

    for (var dat = 0; dat < rating.length; dat++) {
    var sql_rating = '';
    sql_rating = 'INSERT INTO ratings(rating_ids,user_id,ratings,userid,rated_on) VALUES';
        if (dat > 0) {
            sql_rating += ",";
        }                       
        sql_rating += '("' + rating[dat][0] + '","' + rating[dat][1] + '","' + rating[dat][2] + '","' + rating[dat][3] + '","' + rating[dat][4] + '")';

                    sql_rating += ";";
    tx.executeSql(sql_rating);
    }
});
```

Error is:

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: CacheGroups,
>   db=xxx sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Caches,
>   db=xxx  sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Origins,
>   db=xxx  sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table:
>   DeletedCacheResources, db=xxx sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =
>   near ",": syntax error, db=xxx sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =
>   near ",": syntax error, db=xxx  sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =
>   near ",": syntax error, db=xxx  sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =
>   near ",": syntax error, db=xxx sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =
>   near ",": syntax error, db=xxx

please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Your code uses the table name `ratings`, but the error message mentions `Caches`. Are you sure you have shown the correct code?

Comment: @CL actually am creating dynamic tables using in one dirty flag and another i hit the api and push the values into the array.later i insert those values to the corresponding table.here i show one of the insert query. Following info i have in the logcat : sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: CacheGroups, db=xxx sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Caches, db=xxx sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Origins, db=xxx sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: DeletedCacheResources, db=xxx.Can u reply me

Answer (score 0):

Did you change anything in database schema?? please drop all the table and recreate it . Or just reinstall the app. It should resolve . if not let me know.

Comment: even i restart the tablet and reinstall the app.

Comment: can you post the whole error log here..? and which table name you are talking about ?

Comment: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: CacheGroups,
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Caches
 sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Origins,
 sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table:DeletedCacheResources,
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error,
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error,
 sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error, 
 sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error, 
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error,

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample example how to create a table in Sq-lite in phone-gap

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');   // Uncomment to test from scratch, comment for production!
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}
```

Comment: hi,the problem is not about on how to creat the table in phonegap.the thing is error occurs only am try to insert or update the query